# Add a different ActionListener to anonymously referenced JButtons in a JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, jtoolbar

I'm trying to add four JButtons to a JToolBar, each with a different ActionListener.

I'm wondering if there is a way to add an ActionListener to an anonymously referenced JButton, or if I have to specifically define each button and add each listener.

Currently, this is what the code looks like:

```
JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
tools.setFloatable(false);
gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);// adds tools to JPanel gui made in another method

// add buttons to toolbar
tools.add(new JButton("New"));
tools.add(new JButton("Save"));
tools.add(new JButton("Restore"));
tools.addSeparator();
tools.add(new JButton("Quit"));
```

I was wondering if there was a way to add an ActionListener into the `tools.add(new JButton("foo"));` line in the same manner as `Thread t = new FooRunnableClass().start();` or if I would have to define each button, add the ActionListener to each button, then add each button to tools.

Comment: Consider using AbstractActions rather than ActionListeners and thereby set the JButton's Action via `setAction(...)` or via the JButton's constructor.

Comment: `if I would have to define each button, add the ActionListener to each button,` - you need a reference to the button (whether you use the addActionListener() or setAction() method), so yes, that would be the easiest approach.

Comment: Agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels here.  BTW - an `Action` can be directly [added to a `JToolBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html#add-javax.swing.Action-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `addButtonToToolbar` method to help you out (assuming you are using Java 8 or newer):

```
JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
tools.setFloatable(false);
// adds tools to JPanel gui made in another method
gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

addButtonToToolbar(tools, "New", e -> System.out.println("Pressed New"));
addButtonToToolbar(tools, "Save", e -> System.out.println("Pressed Save"));
addButtonToToolbar(tools, "Restore", e -> System.out.println("Pressed Restore"));
tools.addSeparator();
addButtonToToolbar(tools, "Quit", e -> System.out.println("Pressed Quit"));


private void addButtonToToolbar(final JToolBar toolBar, final String buttonText,
                                final ActionListener actionListener) {
    final JButton button = new JButton(buttonText);
    button.addActionListener(actionListener);
    toolBar.add(button);
}
```